# Is the current page the base url in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to see if the current page a user is on is the main page of the website, i.e. there is nothing after the base url.

I'm doing this to exclude some code off the main page.

I asked this question is Javascript, but would like to implement it in PHP

Comment: check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably give you what you are looking for:

```
$is_home = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] === '/' ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

This should give you the url of the current page, when you have this you can check it against the home url.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    // no params
}
```